# Why is my embedded ruby string outputting two strings in the html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following table row with embedded ruby:

```
<tr class=<%= "image-carousel-show thumb-#{index}" %>>
```

Which creates this:

```
<tr class="image-carousel-show" thumb-0="">
```

However, I want the `thumb-0` to be in the class of the row, not as it's own attribute like it currently is.

This is what I want it to show up as:

```
<tr class="image-carousel-show thumb-0">
```

I'm not sure why it's doing this, in the ERB I have it all as one string so I don't know why it's being outputted as two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not done by erb but it is modified by the browser, as those params are not placed within quotes. Try:

```
<tr class="<%= "image-carousel-show thumb-#{index}" %>">
```

Also there is absolutely no sense of having both classes within erb. This will do the same and is slightly more readable.

```
<tr class="image-carousel-show thumb-<%= index %>">
```

Answer (score 4):

Your ERB is compiled to the HTML:

```
<tr class=image-carousel-show thumb-0>
```

Which gets interpreted as:

```
<tr class="image-carousel-show" thumb-0>
```

To fix, you need quotes around your expansion:

```
<tr class="<%= "image-carousel-show thumb-#{index}" %>">
```

I would, however, advise using `content_tag` to avoid the syntactic confusion here:

```
<%= content_tag :tr, class: "image-carousel-show thumb-#{index}" do %>
  <%# tr contents %>
<% end %>
```